# Weird floating point exception

Tags: exception, sigfpe

In the code snippet below I get a floating point exception during run time. I believe the exception happens at the line where division by r is being done. When I comment that line out I get no error.

Also very very strangely when I compile in gcc with the "-g" flag (to try to debug) OR if I insert some "cout statement" immediately after the "if statement" then I don't get any floating point exception at runtime.

I have been staring at my screen on this code for hours, maybe I am making some stupid mistake.. please help!

```
    double prev;
    for(int i=0;i<320;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<320;j++) 
    {
        double x = -8 + i*0.05;
        double y = -8 + j*0.05;
        r= sqrt(x*x+y*y);

        double kappa = atanh(  (2*r)  / ( 2 +  r*r)  );                     

        if( fabs(r) > 1e-7 )
        { 
            prev= ( x*sinh(kappa) )/r; 
        }
         else
        {
            prev=0;         

        }
        /* more stuff */ 
    }
```

UPDATE:
So I was able to fix the problem by adding 1e-15 to the denominator on the contentious line ..

```
prev= ( x*sinh(kappa) )/(r+1e-15);
```

I am still not sure why the if condition gives true ..  for if(fabs(r)>1e-7) when r =0;

Comment: could it be an overflow exception? i mean, `sinh` _does_ grow as O(e^x)

Comment: thanks for that comment.. I replaced that line with simply  prev = 1/r  ... and still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Sqrt of a negitive number? try

```
r= sqrt(fabs(x*x+y*y));
```

on line 7 of your snippet.

Comment: x*x+y*y is guaranteed to be zero or positive

Comment: `negative` multiplied by `negative` is positive. `positive` multiplied by `positive` is `positive`. Any number multiplied by itself will be `positive`. So what number when multiplied by itself will yield a `negative`?

Comment: @kpie interesting! http://speleotrove.com/decimal/daops.html#refsqrt  This link however clarifies that sqrt of signed zero is just signed zero and should not trigger SIGFPE

Comment: This is true. For real though, if cutting of that else statement with a count resolves the error the issue may be prev = 0... /** more stuff **/